# Подключение Ethernet Shield W5100 к ПК напрямую

Tags: arduino

Добрый день!

Решил я по-экспериментировать с шилдом Ethernet W5100, но далеко, к сожалению, не ушёл...
Никак не могу связать в одну сеть сборку Arduino Leonardo + W5100. ПК упорно отказывается видеть подключение.

Тестирую на простом стандартном примере. Пинг не проходит (выдаёт информацию о превышеном времени ожидании и потери всех пакетов ) и соответственно обратиться к вебсерверу через браузер тоже не могу...

Грешил было на кабель т.к. сначала использовал самый обычный, не кроссовый, а затем переобжал старый кабель под кросс и опробовал его. Результат оказался всё тем же.

Подключаю это всё напрямую к ПК за отсутствием роутера.

Так же обратил внимание, что на шилде датчики сигнализируют лишь о наличии питания (PWR).

Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Бьюсь уже не первый вечер.
Сам в этом деле новичок, помогите добрым советом, ребят)

```
 #include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {
0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(80);

void setup() {
// Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
Serial.begin(9600);
while (!Serial) {
; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
}


// start the Ethernet connection and the server:
Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
server.begin();
Serial.print("server is at ");
Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {
// listen for incoming clients
EthernetClient client = server.available();
if (client) {
Serial.println("new client");
// an http request ends with a blank line
boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
while (client.connected()) {
if (client.available()) {
char c = client.read();
Serial.write(c);
// if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
// character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
// so you can send a reply
if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
// send a standard http response header
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
client.println("Connection: close"); // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
client.println("Refresh: 5"); // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
client.println();
client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
client.println("<html>");
// output the value of each analog input pin
for (int analogChannel = 0; analogChannel < 6; analogChannel++) {
int sensorReading = analogRead(analogChannel);
client.print("analog input ");
client.print(analogChannel);
client.print(" is ");
client.print(sensorReading);
client.println("<br />");
}
client.println("</html>");
break;
}
if (c == '\n') {
// you're starting a new line
currentLineIsBlank = true;
} else if (c != '\r') {
// you've gotten a character on the current line
currentLineIsBlank = false;
}
}
}
// give the web browser time to receive the data
delay(1);
// close the connection:
client.stop();
Serial.println("client disconnected");
}
}
```

Comment: А у вас провод перекрёстный или обычный?

Comment: Перекрёстный. Изначально пытался обычным, но в итоге сделал кроссовер. Но результат остался тем же, к сожалению

Comment: Посмотрите здесь, всё ли правильно настроено. http://acerfans.ru/faq/236-kompjuternye-seti.-setevye-podkljuchenija.html

Comment: Прошу прощения за задержку. Спасибо всем за помощь) Отбой тревога)

Проблему нашёл. Оказалось сам шилд косячный. На порте Ethernet транзистор стоял 511-ый.
Погуглив в этом направлении обнаружил, что проблема эта довольно распространённая, ибо мало у кого такие шилды не из китая и раз на раз не приходится.

Снял со старой материнки 510-ый транзистор и поменял. Теперь всё в порядке)